# Windows 10, Ubuntu 18.04 Ubuntu file corruption in dual boot environment

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, mount, filesystem

I use Ubuntu 18.04 on top of AMD, affiliate CPUs, and NVIDA graphics environments.

Windows 10 was installed on `/deV/nvmeXXX` (SSD M.2) and Ubuntu partitioned from `/dev/sda` with a 500G partition.
I installed Ubuntu after installing Windows and use it as multiboot on GRUB2.

Below is the `fdisk -l` result. (GRUB2 is located in `/dev/nvme0n1p1`)

```
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: FBB5D18C-7CB4-4E51-AA8B-8AF39D8D449E

Device           Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1    2048    1085439    1083392   529M Windows recovery environment
/dev/nvme0n1p2 1085440    1290239     204800   100M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p3 1290240    1323007      32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p4 1323008 1953523711 1952200704 930.9G Microsoft basic data


Disk /dev/sda: 3.7 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 3DE6E006-0C99-11EA-B39A-00D8619F3540

Device          Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1          34      32767      32734   16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda2       32768 6765457407 6765424640  3.2T Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda3  6765457408 7814035455 1048578048  500G Linux filesystem
```

In conclusion, the Ubuntu GRUB2 boot screen does not appear, but it is accessed by the GRUB2 Recue Shell, but `/boot/grub` of `(hd1,gpt3)` (Linux installation location) is encrypted (presumed to be corrupted), recovery fails, So I formatted the problem partition and reinstalled Ubuntu from scratch. This problem occurred only two days after installation. At the time, I installed only the basic graphics driver and VS Code, so it doesn't seem to be a problem with installation conflicts.

The problem is that after 3 days of re-installation, the file is corrupted and the file system becomes read-only. The `fsck` command fixed the corruption, but I am concerned that this is a conflict issue with Windows. (In the meantime, I booted into Windows.)

It is possible to assume that it is a problem with the HDD where the Linux partition is located, but it has been less than 6 months since the purchase of the computer device including the HDD.

Please let me know if you have any expected advice or feedback. Sorry for the lack of hints provided.

Comment: Did you install any Windows drivers that allow you to read/write to Linux ext2/3/4 partitions? Is your sda an external USB disk?

Comment: @heynnema
sda is a 4TB HDD internal hard disk! (It is not hard external.)

And.. I haven't installed the driver for ext 2/3/4 access on Windows. Do you think this part will affect the file corruption?

Comment: I assume that you added the 4TB disk to the computer at purchase time, yes? How did you prep it? Did you install a fresh GPT partition table? I also don't see a swap partition. Edit your question and show me `free -h`. We may end up running a memory diagnostic, based on your reply.